# Dreamweaver - Search in all html files which does not have <header> tag

Tags: dreamweaver

I am using dreamweaver CC version.

I want to search in all HTML files which **does not have `<header>`** tag..

Having 130 html files, out of these I have around 50 files **without** `<header>` tag, how can I search and replace in these html files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose Edit > Find and Replace, or press Ctrl-F (Cmd-F).

The Find and Replace dialog appears.

From the Find in pop-up menu, choose one of the options for the scope of your search.

From the Search pop-up menu, choose Source Code

Choose Source Code to search the HTML in Code view.

In the Find field, type the word or phrase that you’re looking for.
In the Replace field, type the replacement word or phrase.
Depending on what you want to do, click Find Next, Find All, Replace, or Replace All.

Comment: Hi **@SaucedApples**.. Thanks, but this is not I was looking for.. please check the updated question...

Comment: If they are all in the same project, it should search them all.  I have used Dreamweaver for many years and only know of this function.